# Don't Generate Same Random Number in C +- 2

Tags: c, random, numbers, srand

```
srand(time(NULL));

for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   int randomNumber = (rand() % 100) + 1  // gets a random number from 0 - 100.
   // do stuff
}
```

I've currently got a random number variable which stores a number from 0-100 in each iteration of the for loop, and the code below then does stuff with that random number variable. However I've noticed that with each iteration of the loop, sometimes the same random number gets generated, and other times it generates a number very close to the one I've already generated. E.g: when
`i = 1` the randomNumber might be 50, but when `i = 2`, it could be 51. This is super annoying for the thing I'm coding. Is there a way I can make it so that if it generates 50 the first time, the second time it has to generate a number 2 integers away from the one it just generated. E.g. if it just generates 50, then the second time it can't generate 48,49,50,51,52, but it still generates between 0-100, just skipping these numbers. Then it repeats the same thing when  a new randomNumber is generated.

Comment: so just loop until you have a suitable number.

Comment: @xing: That is not the issue here.

Comment: @KenWhite: This is clearly a request for a distribution other than one of independent uniform samples over [1, 100]. Yes, samples chosen with a dependence on prior samples may still be random.

Comment: @EricPostpischil sure thing, but considering that the `srand(time(NULL))` is probably the reason for "duplicates" then, anything is an improvement already :D

Comment: What behavior do you want when the previous sample was 100? Should 1 or 2 be considered close to that because they wrap? Or should only 98, 99, and 100 be excluded?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: No, `srand(time(NULL))` is not the reason for the duplicates. The question clearly shows a loop selecting 100 samples with no intervening `srand`, and it asks about samples “with each iteration of the loop,” not with different executions of the entire loop or program.

Comment: If you need 100 numbers between1 and 100 without dupes, fill an array with 1-100 and shuffle it.

Comment: You just don't want nearby numbers to be consecutive? So it's OK if it goes 10 20 10 20 10 20 because they're more than 2 apart from each other?

Comment: The "problems" you describe are precisely the properties of random numbers, so clearly you don't want random numbers. Describe to us what you actually want to do, and we might be able to help you do it.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: Potential samples that are near prior samples are properties of a uniform distribution of independent samples, not of random numbers generally. The question describes what they actually want to do: Exclude numbers near the previous sample from the distribution for the current sample.

Comment: The code (initially) generates numbers from 1 to 100, but the comment says 0 to 100. Which is desired?

Comment: @EricPostpischil He hasn't even gotten on the plane flying to the country of saying what he really wants to do. He's said nothing but "I have this number, it behaves this way, I want it to behave that way". *WHY* does he want that? Is he trying to make a display of random-looking dots? Is he trying to select semi-random questions for a quiz? Is he trying to shuffle music selections? That's what we need to know to help.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: Some confirmation and clarification would help, but it is quite likely the request is to draw a first sample from a uniform distribution over the integers in [1, 100] and to draw subsequent samples from a uniform distribution over the integers in [1, 100]−[x-2, x+2], where x is the previous sample. Regardless, your statement that the properties are “precisely the properties of random numbers” is false and unhelpful.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to get the random number in a loop that checks if it's too close to the last number.

```
srand(time(NULL));
int lastRandom = -2;
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    int randomNumber;
    do {
        randomNumber = (rand() % 100) + 1;  // gets a random number from 0 - 100.
    } while (randomNumber >= lastRandom - 2 && randomNumber <= lastRandom + 2);
    lastRandom = randomNumber;
    // do stuff
}
```

Normally I wouldn't suggest calling `rand()` in a loop, because this might go on too long if the acceptance criteria is too strict. But this only rejects about 5%, so it's not likely to repeat many times.

Comment: Added the missing `;` that came from the original code.

Answer (score 1):

What you might do if you don't mind getting the same number more than once (as long as it is not in a row) but you do not want an inner loop that tries getting a new number, is:

1. Get a random number between 1 and 100 normally in the first loop.
2. After that, adding a random number between 3 and 97 to the last number and then using modulo 100 will get you a random number in the range 1 to 100, excluding numbers in the range `oldNum - 2` to `oldNum + 2`.

   (Note that this wraps the range of excluded numbers so that for example, if the last number was 100, then 1 and 2 will also be excluded).

```c
srand(time(NULL));

int randomNumber;
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   if (i == 0) {
       randomNumber = (rand() % 100) + 1;  // gets a random number from 1 - 100.
   } else {
       randomNumber = ((randomNumber + (rand() % 95) + 3) % 100) + 1;
   }
   // do stuff
}
```

If you do not want the list of excluded number to wrap (for example if the last number was 99, then you would only want to exclude 97, 98, 99 and 100) then it's slightly more complicated:

1. You still want to get a random number between 1 and 100 normally in the first loop.
2. After that, the default option would be to add a random number between 3 and 97 to the last number and then use modulo 100 to get you a random number in the range 1 to 100, excluding numbers in the range `oldNum - 2` to `oldNum + 2`.

   But before getting to the default options, you would need to check if the old number is either so low or so high that the range of the excluded numbers would wrap around:

   a. If the old number is so low that the range of excluded numbers would wrap then we want a random number in the range from `oldNum + 3` to 100.

   b. If the old number is so high that the range of excluded numbers would wrap then we want a random number in the range from 1 to `oldNum - 3`.

```c
srand(time(NULL));

int randomNumber;
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   if (i == 0) {
       randomNumber = (rand() % 100) + 1;  // gets a random number from 1 - 100.
   } else {
        if (randomNumber < 3) {
        /* Old number is so low that excluded numbers would wrap if we would
         * be using the 'default' way.
         * We want a random number in the range from randomNumber + 3 to 100:
         */
            randomNumber += (rand() % (98 - randomNumber)) + 3; 
        }
        else if (randomNumber > 98) {
        /* Old number is so high that excluded numbers would wrap if we would
         * be using the 'default' way.
         * We want a random number in the range from 1 to randomNumber - 3:
         */
            randomNumber = (rand() % (randomNumber - 3)) + 1; 
        } else {
        /* Default way. 
         * We want a random number in the range 1 to 100, excluding numbers in the 
         * range randomNumber - 2 to randomNumber + 2
         */
            randomNumber = ((randomNumber + (rand() % 95) + 3) % 100) + 1;
        }
   }
   // do stuff
}
```

If somebody has the same problem but wants number in a different range and/or wants the range of excluded numbers to be different, here's the same code but with constants instead of "magic numbers":

```c
srand(time(NULL));

int randomNumber;
int const maxNum = 100; // Random number must be in the range from 1 to maxNum
int const exclude = 2;  // New random number must NOT be in the range
                        // from (oldNum - exclude) to (oldNum + exclude)
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   if (i == 0) {
       randomNumber = (rand() % maxNum) + 1;  // gets a random number from 1 to maxNum.
   } else {
        if (randomNumber <= exclude) {
        /* Old number is so low that excluded numbers would wrap if we would
         * be using the 'default' way.
         * We want a random number in the range from (randomNumber + exclude + 1)
         * to maxNum:
         */
            randomNumber += (rand() % (maxNum - exclude - randomNumber)) + exclude + 1; 
        }
        else if (randomNumber > maxNum - exclude) {
        /* Old number is so high that excluded numbers would wrap if we would
         * be using the 'default' way.
         * We want a random number in the range from 1 to (randomNumber - exclude - 1):
         */
            randomNumber = (rand() % (randomNumber - exclude - 1)) + 1; 
        } else {
        /* Default way. 
         * We want a random number in the range 1 to 100, excluding numbers in the 
         * range randomNumber - exclude to randomNumber + exclude
         */
            randomNumber = ((randomNumber + (rand() % (maxNum - 2*exclude - 1) 
                    + exclude + 1) % maxNum) + 1;
        }
   }
   // do stuff
}
```